# Eclipse does not retain my unsaved editing when I switch to another buffer and then switch back

Tags: eclipse, edit

I frequently lose my editing in Eclipse when I switch from a buffer to another. I am using MugSoft's Enacs+'s plugin in Eclipse. This plugin allows one to use most of the Emacs shortcuts in Eclipse. But I feel often confused when I switch to some buffer using "ctrl + b" and then switched back using the same shortcut. My unsaved editing in the original buffer got abandoned definitively by Eclipse, so that I can not even recover it using 'undo' facilities.

Do you have some similar issues? Is it normal??

Thanks for your ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the Emacs plugin and see if the problem persists. Otherwise, I recommend trying to reinstall Eclipse :) Probably the easiest way to fix something like this. If you re-install the Emacs plugin and the problem comes back, then you know where the problem is, and should probably file a bug report.

Note: (It could be a feature of the plugin, so make sure you check all of the preferences as well.)